# Change table row highlighting to white border

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I wanted to ask if it is possible to change the CSS so that the table rows are not highlighted in colour - but just have white border - when you hover over them?

The CSS is as follows:

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: #0D0D0D;
}

tr:hover{
    background: grey;
    }


tr:hover td{
  background: transparent !important;
}



</style>
```

And here is the full table:
https://jsfiddle.net/aqjccpvx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aqjccpvx/1/

Add this to your css rules:

```
tr:hover{
  background: #403151;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

EDIT:
If you want to fix the moving rows when hovering replace this:

```
border: 1px solid white;
```

With:

```
outline: 1px solid white;
```

Fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aqjccpvx/4/

Comment: Ah you beat me ^_^

Comment: FANTASTIC - I LOVE THIS PLACE - can you please check the html - the table moves a little when the first row is highlighted - can you please tell me why?

Comment: It's because the border is added so the row gets a bigger height

Comment: THAT IS JUST SUPERB - THANK YOU SO MUCH!))))!)!)!)

Comment: You're welcome! Accept my answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: one more thing - if I wanted to change outline color to custom - how I can do that?

Comment: What do you mean with custom? If you want to change the color of the outline just replace `white` with your prefered color

Comment: I replaced it to this                                                                                   ttr:hover{
  border: 1px solid 0D0D0D;
}                                               and it did not work(

Comment: It has to be `#0D0D0D`

Comment: I had a very short question - can we not affect the background colour and keep it as it is? when I remove:  background: #403151;    it makes the rows black...

Comment: ALL DONE THNAKS!)

Comment: can you also please test this style in Internet Explorer: tr:hover{
  outline: 1px solid white;
}
for some reason it paints borders in white and keeps them that way after you remove the cursor...

Comment: Please ask a new question if you get a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible:

Simply change your css to:

```
tr:hover{
  border: 1px solid white;
}


tr:hover td{
  background: #403151;
}
```